# Add a string to an ArrayList

Tags: java, string, arraylist

Please help. I can't get this to work:

```
List<AddNewClientSaveAction> data = new ArrayList<AddNewClientSaveAction>();
// AddNewClientSaveAction is a class that collects user input from a number of JTextField values
String line;
            final String lastEntryClient = "LAST_ENTRY";

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.startsWith(lastEntryClient)) {
                    data.add(lastEntryClient);
                }
            }
```

I'm trying to add the String 'lastEntryClient' to the ArayList 'data', but I keep getting a code error highlight.

Sorry if it's too obvious. Am a newbie at JAVA.

Comment: Can you add the declaration of `data` please?

Comment: What's the error, please provide and let us know where it is giving it.

Comment: What is ```e``` good for? This really doesn't make any sense.

Comment: "no suitable method for add(String)"

Comment: Paste here what data contents br.

Comment: Are you getting an error, or just a warning?

Comment: We also need the declaration/instantiation of `data`.

Comment: I'm trying to get the position of a line that starts with LAST_ENTRY in a text file using 'int e = line.indexOf(lastEntryClient);'

Comment: @OliverMuchai: And have you CREATED your ArrayList? Do you have somewhere in your code the information in the answer given below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are declaring list as

```
 ArrayList data = new ArrayList();
```

then you get the message about parameterizing the list because data can hold any `Object`

If you know that you are going to add only strings in your list, declare it as

```
 ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>(); // pre java 7
 ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>(); // valid for java 7
```

Comment: add <> after equals sign.  Ex; ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>(); is valid in java 7.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
   List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();// this is for java 7 and won't compile in previous versions.

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.startsWith(lastEntryClient)) {
            data.add(line);
        }
    }
```

use `List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>()` for versions before java 7

Answer (score 1):

What is `AddNewClientSaveAction`? By using this, you are creating a list which is prepared to accept Objects of that particular class. But you are trying to pass String objects to it. Which do you really want?

It sounds like you want a List of String types instead:

```
List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Either that, or instead of adding the String object to it, add something from the AddNewClientSaveAction class instead. It's difficult to know which you want without knowing more about your code.

Answer (score 0):

This will add String to the array list:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
list.add("hello");
System.out.println(list);
```